# Unable to replace dmenu with rofi combi mode

Tags: i3

I'm unable to add a key binding for the following command in the i3 config file : `rofi -combi-modi window,drun -show combi`.

I'm trying to add the following entry to the `.config/i3/config` file : `bindsym $mod+t exec rofi -combi-modi window,drun -show combi` but this is not working.

I'm wondering why this is not working for me ?

However using this binding : `bindsym $mod+t exec rofi -modi drun -show drun` does the expected job.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

i3 interprets commas and colons specially so if you are using those characters you need to quote your exec command.

```
$mod+t exec "rofi -combi-modi window,drun -show combi"
```

Reference: https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#exec and https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#command_chaining

Comment: that was helpful, thanks a lot